# Error when installing android application

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I trying to use C2DM in my android application, but after I added it I can't install the application. I get this error "Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED". But I can't see whats wrong.

Anyone that know what I have done wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="Wordy.Game"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="0.1"
          android:installLocation="preferExternal">
          <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

          <permission
            android:name="Wordy.Game.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
          <uses-permission 
            android:name="Wordy.Game.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

        <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/wordy">
            <activity android:name="Main"
                      android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <receiver
                android:name=".C2DMRegistrationReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" >
                    </action>
                    <category android:name="Wordy.Game" />
                </intent-filter>            
            </receiver>
             <receiver
                android:name=".C2DMRegistrationReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" >
                    </action>
                    <category android:name="Wordy.Game" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>



      <activity android:name="Result" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
              <activity android:name="PlayField" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
              <activity android:name="Game" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
              <activity android:name="News" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
              <activity android:name="PlayOnline" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />     
              <activity android:name="UsersOnline" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />        
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found whats wrong, the package name on the application was not allowed to start with capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

try prefixing your activityies with a . or the full package name:

```
<activity android:name="com.gizm0.YourClass"></activvity>
```

or

```
  <activity android:name=".YourClass"></activvity>
```

Comment: I will try that, but it has worked before I add the C2DM stuff.

Comment: Ok, I see. It did work until you installed C2DM. Have looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198097/c2dm-permission-c2d-message-gives-installation-error He also seems to have the same problem

Comment: I looked at it before I post my question, but I didn't found anything that helped me. I have used this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Comment: What is the logcat output during installation?

Comment: Logcat says: Bad class name Wordy.Game.permission.C2D_MESSAGE in package Wordy.Game